# Notifications on Android Wear only from Message API not showing in peek view

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to create a notification on a wear device only.
I am successfully sending a message using the Wear Message API and constructing a notification but it does not show as a peek style.  You have to slide up from the watch face to see the notification, meaning most users wouldn't know it was there.  What I want is the preview peek quarter face style that you can then slide up to see the full notification.

This notification code works fine if I just send from the mobile app, but I want this notification to be displayed on wear only and later have custom activities on additional pages.

Below is the relevant code, I'm guessing I'm missing some sort of attribute to get it to peek but cannot find it.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {
    String path = messageEvent.getPath();
    byte[] data = messageEvent.getData();

    if (path.equals(MSG_QUOTE)) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Quote Received");

        String quote = new String(data);

        NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle bigStyle = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        bigStyle.bigText(quote);

        Notification notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setContentText(quote)
                    .setStyle(bigStyle)
                    .build();

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);

        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificationBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We (iHeartRadio) are doing wear-only notifications and I've seen what you describe in two scenarios: certain watch faces on the LG G doesn't show peek view and if the notifications are muted on the watch.
You're code seems correct, so shouldn't be that.

You also need to make sure that there's no other notification with a higher priority than you in the stream, set yours higher (for testing) or clear all notifications.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation I was doing everything correctly.

I've just done some more investigation.
It seems the latest LG update that I got this morning (4.4W.2) is the cause of the trouble.
If you have the option "Hide cards on dimmed screen" set to Always Hide then that causes NO cards to be displayed, even if the screen is on!
Seems like a wear bug when they introduced the new slide down to hide for later.

The higher priority is a good tip so I'll accept your answer since it adds something to getting the notifications to display.

Comment: Thanks, great to know that LG rolled this out!